# i want to refresh the checkboxes when i click on the eventlistner button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick, addeventlistener

when i click on my eventlistener which makes it go to the next question, i want the checkboxes to kind of "refresh". now it stucks on what the player answered on the previous questing, please give me som help

```
<span id="choices" class="hidden">
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice1" class="checkboxes"> <span id="answer1"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice2" class="checkboxes"> <span id="answer2"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice3" class="checkboxes"> <span id="answer3"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice4" class="checkboxes"> <span id="answer4"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px">
  <button id="next"> Next</button>
</span>
```

the eventlistner

```
next.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (quiz.checkAnswer()) {
    quiz.score++;
  };
  console.log(quiz.checkAnswer());
  quiz.nextQuestion();
  quiz.display();
  if(quiz.currentQuestion < quiz.quests.length) {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = quiz.quests[quiz.currentQuestion].question;
    document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = quiz.quests[quiz.currentQuestion].answer[0].alt;
    document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = quiz.quests[quiz.currentQuestion].answer[1].alt;
    document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = quiz.quests[quiz.currentQuestion].answer[2].alt;
    document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = quiz.quests[quiz.currentQuestion].answer[3].alt;
  }  
  quiz.setName();
  quiz.setnoOfQuestions();
  quiz.progress();
  quiz.amountOfQuestions();
  quiz.finalScore();
});
```

Comment: it says it is checked when i click next to the next question

Comment: is this in a form?

Comment: simpliest way is to use form reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the possibles way is

```
const kases = document.querySelectorAll('#choice1, #choice2, #choice3, #choice4')

// ...

next.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  //...
  kases.forEach( k=>k.checked = false )
  //...

}
```